# Formating the code with temperatures

Tags: java

Working on a problem and got the Fahrenheit list that I need but I don't really know how to add another list next to it and have it do the math as well. Please help, Thank you.

The Problem:

A program that generates a two-column table showing Fahrenheit temperatures from -40F to 120F and their equivalent Celsius temperatures. Each line in the table should be 5 degrees F more than the previous one. Both the Fahrenheit and Celsius temperatures should be accurate to 1 decimal place.

My Attempt:

```
    package chapter5;
    public class Assignment2 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        //T(°C) = (T(°F) - 32) × 5/9
        int F = 120;
        int count = 0;
        int C = (F - 32) * (5/9);

        while (F >= -40 && F <= 120 ){
            if (F % 5 == 0){
                System.out.printf("%-5d",F);
                count++;    
            }
            if (count == 1){
               System.out.println();
               count = 0;
            }
            F--;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Try using `double` for your expressions

Comment: you do not actually state what your problem is

Comment: why is `&& F <= 120` needed?  You are only counting down

Comment: `count` would be better off boolean, but actually the `if` statement would simply be done unconditionally in the first `if`

Comment: and most importantly `C` is not being re-calculated for each `F` and is not being printed either

Comment: Michael, some people have gone to some trouble here, so please uvote and accept and answer if it fulfills your needs. If it doesn't please comment to that effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */
package chapter5;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */

public class Assignment2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //T(°C) = (T(°F) - 32) × 5/9
        final String DEGREE  = "\u00b0";
        int F = -40;        
        float C = 0.0F;

        while (F <= 120 ){

            C = (F - 32)*(0.5556F);

            System.out.printf("%d%sF  \t\t\t%.1f%sC\n", F, DEGREE, C, DEGREE);
            F = F + 5;
        }
    }   
}
```

---

**Output**

```
-40°F           -40.0°C
-35°F           -37.2°C
-30°F           -34.4°C
-25°F           -31.7°C
-20°F           -28.9°C
-15°F           -26.1°C
-10°F           -23.3°C
-5°F            -20.6°C
0°F             -17.8°C
5°F             -15.0°C
10°F            -12.2°C
15°F            -9.4°C
20°F            -6.7°C
25°F            -3.9°C
30°F            -1.1°C
35°F            1.7°C
40°F            4.4°C
45°F            7.2°C
50°F            10.0°C
55°F            12.8°C
60°F            15.6°C
65°F            18.3°C
70°F            21.1°C
75°F            23.9°C
80°F            26.7°C
85°F            29.4°C
90°F            32.2°C
95°F            35.0°C
100°F           37.8°C
105°F           40.6°C
110°F           43.3°C
115°F           46.1°C
120°F           48.9°C
```

Comment: OP states temperatures should be accurate to 1 decimal place

Comment: OK, but what are those `import`'s for?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Now, is it okay for problem.

Comment: Yep, if you used the `"\u00b0"` char it would really pop

Comment: How would you get the F formatted with one decimal place as well?

Comment: For F formatted with one decimal places, you can make F as float `float F` and use `System.out.printf("%.1f%sF    \t\t\t%.1f%sC\n", F, DEGREE, C, DEGREE);`

Answer (score 0):

Look at printf [format specification](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to print out in a tab mode both the F and C temperatures.

Also you need to do your calculations in a float or a double.

And you can write your loop in increments of 5 instead of looping through everything and checking for %5.

Answer (score 0):

I used `System.out.printf` to format output in eclipse console.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        double F = -40;

        for (; F < 120; F += 5) {
            double C = (F - 32) * 5 / 9;
            C = BigDecimal.valueOf(C).setScale(1,RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue();
            System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s \n", F, C);
        }
    }
```

This program takes one Farenheit value converts it to celsium, prints both in two columns and increments farenheit value by 5 and converts it to celsium again.

It uses `java.lang.BigDecimal` to round double value to 1 decimal place. This is done in method `setScale(1,RoundingMode.CEILING)`

Comment: OP states *temperatures should be accurate to 1 decimal place*

Comment: What does it mean `1 decimal place`?

Comment: e.g. `3.1` or `9.0`

Comment: Temperatures are incremented by `5` but not by `5.5`. And initial temperature is  `-40`. Where is decimal place here?

Comment: **No** the output should be accurate to 1 decimal place, which is not acheivale using an `int` to store the value of `C`

Comment: does not compile

Comment: I forgot to change type of `C` and `F` to double

Answer (score 0):

I just have a for loop where I decrement by five, so I don't have to check if it could be divided by five.

In my solution, I convert from fahrenheit directly before printing.

Suggested by **@Scary Wombat** I used `%.1f%n` to display the celsius temperature with one decimal line place and a line separator.

---

**Update:** Added `"\u00b0F"` and `"\u00b0C"` to add the Strings **°F** and **°C**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //T(°C) = (T(°F) - 32) × 5/9
    for (int F = 120;F >= -40; F-=5){
            System.out.printf("%-3d\u00b0F %.1f\u00b0C%n",F, (double) ((F - 32d) * 5/9));
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.printf("%-5d %.1f%n",F, (double) ((F - 32) * 5/9));` ?

Comment: Yes, it prints out the fahrenheit temperature first and then the conversioned Celsius temperature.

Comment: My apologies, what I am trying to say, is to not use a separate `System.out.println();` but to use `%n` - what do you think?

Comment: Oh, I'm very sorry. I didn't see the 'n'. Yes, it is much better indeed. Found the second `System.out.println();` ugly too. Thank you :)

Comment: @ScaryWombat is it okay for you to use it in my answer?

Comment: Please do, thats why I suggest it

Comment: How would you get the F formatted with one decimal place as well?

Comment: I would change **F** to a double and print it out just as celsius like this: `%.1f`, which prints out a number accurate to 1 decimal place.

Answer (score -1):

How about this:

```
// Each Celsius degree is calculated in the cycle.
double CasDouble = (F - 32.) * (5./9.);

// The double value is rounded to an integer
int C = (int) CasDouble;

// The application prints the Fahrenheit and Celsius degrees
System.out.printf("%-5d\t%-5d",F,C);
```

So:

```
package chapter5;

public class Assignment2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // T(°C) = (T(°F) - 32) × 5/9
        int F = 120;
        int count = 0;

        while (F >= -40 && F <= 120) {
            if (F % 5 == 0) {

                // Each Celsius degree is calculated in the cycle.
                double CasDouble = (F - 32.) * (5. / 9.);

                // The double value is rounded to an integer
                int C = (int) CasDouble;

                // The application prints the Fahrenheit and Celsius degrees
                System.out.printf("%-5d\t%-5d", F, C);

                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1) {
                System.out.println();
                count = 0;
            }
            F--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please try to add some explanation along with the code too.